# Broken positioning of a <ul> menu element

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I am trying to position a website navigation on the right of the header. However, the existing code is really messy and I just can't get it to work.

I am talking about the navigation at this website's header - https://softuni.bg/ Notice how it's broken and positioned below the header.

I want it to look like this:

[image]

The Main problem is that all of it is in a  tag, which has a certain width. However, if you are logged in as a user, you get an extra item in the menu and it falls on a second line..

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code in your id #logInBtn>li>a

Your Code:

```
#logInBtn>li>a {
background: #ff9c00;
border-radius: 0;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

Modified Coad:

```
#logInBtn>li>a {
background: #ff9c00;
border-radius: 0;
padding-left: 12px;
padding-right: 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;                /* Modifide line  */
margin-left: 250px;      /* Modifide line  */
}
```